# django get_or_create int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error when I try to user get_or_create 
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'

```
for ubc in Ubc.objects.all():
        professional_grade, created = ProfessionalGrade.objects.get_or_create(ubc=ubc)
        if created:
            professional_grade.category=0,
            professional_grade.category_name="BRUTA"
        professional_grade.experts = 0
        professional_grade.coordinators = 0
        professional_grade.seniors = 0
        professional_grade.researchers = 0
        professional_grade.plenos = 0
        professional_grade.experience = 0
        professional_grade.masters = 0
        professional_grade.doctors = 0
        professional_grade.save()
```

Comment: Just remove comma in this line: `professional_grade.category=0,`. Python consider `0,` as tuple.

Comment: Thanks a lot I did not pay attention on it